# Generate a Google Calendar compatible feed

Tags: google-calendar-api, atom-feed

I'm trying to build a Google Calendar compatible feed (atom), that users can subscribe to and use to receive updates, but everything I've read so far involves communicating with Google using the GData APIs. I just want to provide a feed url that can be added to Google Calendar if the user chooses to do so.

When I tried adding the `<gd:where>` and `<gd:who>` elements to a 'normal' atom feed, it broke in my feed reader.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Zahymaka -- did you ever find a solution to this?  I've read that google calendar isn't great at auto-updating with ics, that it sometimes takes a long time to do so, and it doesn't update changed events.  I'd love to hear what you ended up doing, as I'm thinking I'll need to go with the gdata api.  Here's my posting on the topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158507/how-to-publish-a-dynamic-event-feed-for-google-calendar

Comment: No I didn't. I'm stuck with ics at the moment.

Comment: Ok. It looks like that's what I'm going to do too.  Have you found google to update from your ics feed quickly and reliably?

Comment: I didn't check that because I had to generate all the events to look like one-time events. The recurrences I was using were more varied than the iCalendar spec, eg a frequent recurrence was 5th week -- not last week -- for months that has a fifth week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be being dense, but if you are trying to provide users with calendar info, would it not be a better idea to use the ICS format?

Comment: I already have available ics, but am not very familiar with Google calendar. Does Google Calendar autoupdate with ics?

Answer (score 0):

not really an answer but the Rome API may be useful

https://rome.dev.java.net/

Karl

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox and view the source of a Google Calendar feed and then as it to a server it will not work. Why not?

Try it your self.

view-source:http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en@holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic